# Return values of certain key in a nested dictionary and form a hierarchy dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I have a nested dictionary that looks like below:

```
d= {"key1":"A", "key2":"B", "score1":0.1, "score2":0.4, "depth":0, 
"chain":[
 {"key1":"A1", "key2":"B1", "score1":0.2, "score2":0.5, "depth":1, 
  "chain":[{"key1":"A11", "key2":"B11","score1":0.3, "score2":0.6, "depth":2}, 
         {"key1":"A12", "key2":"B12","score1":0.5, "score2":0.7, "depth":2}]
 },
 {"key1":"A2", "key2":"B2","score1":0.1, "score2":0.2,"depth":1,
  "chain":[{None, None, None, None, None}, 
         {"key1":"A22", "key2":"B22","score1":0.1, "score2":0.5, "depth":2}]
 }
    ]
}
```

I want to create a function that when I call `fun(key1, d)`, it could return me a dictionary keeping the original hierarchy, but within each level, it will return the value of key1, and sum up the value of score1 and score2, like below:

```
{"A":0.5, "depth":0,
"chain":[
 {"A1":0.7, "depth":1,
  "chain":[{"A11":0.9,"depth":2}, 
         {"A12":1.3, "depth":2}]
 },
 {"A2":0.3,"depth":1,
  "chain":[None, 
         {"A22":0.6, "depth":2}]
 }
    ]
}
```

How can I do this? 
I have tried

```
def gen_dict_extract(key, input_dic):
    return {input_dic[key]:input_dic["score1"]+input_dic["score2"],
        "depth":input_dic["depth"], 
        "chain": gen_dict_extract(key,input_dic["chain"])}
```

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. Also, do not name variables after built-ins (`d`, not `dict`). Have you made any attempt so far?

Comment: you enter "string_121" and it outputs .3+.8?

Comment: Please *show* your desired output and indicate what you have tried already. See [mcve].

Comment: @jpp Sorry for not being clearer, but I have just edited my question to make it clearer with desired output and what I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with the solution you've tried:

- `chain` is not guaranteed to be present and
- `chain` is a list of dictionaries and you are treating it as a single dictionary

Hopefully the following does what you want it to do:

```
def gen_dict_extract(key, input_dic):
    rv = {
        input_dic[key]: input_dic["score1"] + input_dic["score2"],
        "depth": input_dic["depth"],
    }
    if "chain" in input_dic:
        rv["chain"] = [gen_dict_extract(key, x) for x in input_dic["chain"]]
    return rv
```

Comment: Since I have simplified my question a bit in the previous post, I couldn't apply the function you provided here and got what I wanted. The problem is, sometimes I have None as an element in the list "chain", if that is the case, I would like to return None as well. I updated the question to reflect this point, and added an updated answer based on the solution you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have some None in the list of "chain", the following function worked in the end, which has some slight updates based on the solution @dvk provided:

```
def gen_dict_extract(key, input_dic):
rv = {
    input_dic[key]: input_dic["score1"] + input_dic["score2"],
    "depth": input_dic["depth"],
}
if "chain" in input_dic:
    rv["chain"]=[]
    for x in input_dic["chain"]:
        if x is not None:
            rv["chain"].insert(input_dic["chain"].index(x),gen_dict_extract(key, x))
return rv
```